# :not() on click event still firing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following example structure:

```
<div class="modHolder">
  <div id="wData">...</div>
</div>
```

I want something to happen if `.modHolder` is clicked but nothing to happen if `#wData` is clicked.

This is what I'm trying but `#wData` is still reacting to the click:

```
$(document).on('click', '.modHolder:not("#wData"), .modClose', function(e) {
...
}
```

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to do it, use this for clicking `.modHolder`:

```
$(document).on('click', '.modHolder, .modClose', function(e) {
    ...
});
```

and then add this:

```
$(document).on('click', '#wData', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

This will stop the clickEvent to bubble up the DOM-tree.

Check it out here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1s17Lso8/)

Answer (score 0):

Your selector is wrong. Try replacing

```
'.modHolder:not("#wData")'
```

with

```
'.modHolder div:not("#wData")'
```

Here's a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/muywo9qp/

Comment: Will this work if the elements to be ignored are not direct children of the `.modHolder` div? What additional handling will have to be done in that case?

Answer (score 0):

It should rather be:

```
$(document).on('click', '.modHolder', function(e) { ... });
$(document).on('click', '#wData', function(e) {
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
});
```

```js
$(document).on('click', '.modHolder', function(e) { 
  alert('Here');
});
$(document).on('click', '#wData', function(e) {
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modHolder">
  <div id="wData">.....</div>
  <div class="modClose">X</div>
</div>
```